# How to check dependencies in generics with ArchUnitTest?

Tags: java, generics, archunit

We have a rule that package "foo" should not depend on package "bar"

```
noClasses()
                .that()
                .resideInAPackage("com.foo..")
                .should()
                .dependOnClassesThat(resideInAPackage("com.bar.."))
                .check(javaClasses);
```

And we have an interface in "foo" using "bar" in two ways, directly and via generics.

```
public interface IFoo {

    BarClass getBar();

    Optional<BarClass> getOptionalBar();

    List<BarClass> getListBar();
}
```

The "BarClass getBar();" is caught by ArchUnitTest, but "Optional getOptionalBar()" and "List getListBar()" doesn't give us any error in the test. Does anybody know how to make them failing too?

Comment: Which version of ArchUnit are you using? [ArchUnit 0.20.0](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/releases/tag/v0.20.0) has introduced support for generic return types. With that, type arguments of generic method return types should be considered as class dependencies.

Comment: Good point. 0.17.0. Let me try with the latest one...

Comment: That helped, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ArchUnit 0.20.0](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/releases/tag/v0.20.0) has introduced support for generic return types.
With the current version, type arguments of generic method return types should automatically be considered as class dependencies.