# ArchUnit doesn't detect generic forbidden dependencies

Tags: java, generics, archunit

I'm using ArchUnit to detect forbidden dependencies from the controller (`C`) to the entity (`E`).

Example  :

```
layeredArchitecture()
    .consideringOnlyDependenciesInLayers()
    .layer("Controller").definedBy(controllerPredicate)
    .layer("Service").definedBy(servicePredicate)
    .layer("Entity").definedBy(entityPredicate)

    .whereLayer("Controller").mayOnlyAccessLayers("Service")
    .whereLayer("Entity").mayOnlyBeAccessedByLayers("Service")
    .check(...);
```

The dependency is detected if there is a direct dependency from `C` to `E` :

```
E entity = new E();
```

But it's not detected if there is a depenency from `C` to `Optional<E>` :

```
Optional<E> optionalEntity = service.returningAnOptionalEntity();
```

I'm using the `1.0.1` version. And I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70680064/how-to-check-dependencies-in-generics-with-archunittest) that generics should be supported since `0.0.20` but it doesn't seem to.

Any way to detect these generic dependencies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use a specific API of your entity (i.e. call a method or access a field) in your controller, ArchUnit cannot detect a dependency (see also [ArchUnit#1012](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/1012), which basically describes the same use case).

This is unrelated to generics; you wouldn't get a violation even if your service returned a non-`Optional` entity `E`.